# How do photons travel at a speed that should be impossible to attain?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, photons

If it requires infinite amount of energy to travel at the speed of light then how photon attains this speed? Its source is never infinitely sourced.

Comment: If no animal can be transformed into a duck, then how can a duck be a duck?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Massless particles don't need infinite energy to jump at $c$. Photons don't have rest mass as they don't interact with Higgs field.

What you have heard is applied only for mass. The whole thing works like this:
In relativistic physics, mass isn't constant. It is increased when its speed is increased. It is driven by this formula: $$m=\frac{M}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^2}}$$ where, $m$ is relativistic mass, $M$ is rest mass, $v$ is speed.

So, at higher speed, we need higher energy to accelerate mass because it has been increased.
In case of massless particle, let's apply this formula:

1. When $v$ is less than $c$: If you divide $0$ by a positive number, the result would be $0$. So, to accelerate $0$ relativistic mass particle, you wouldn't need energy. That's the reason why you can't find a massless particle at speed lesser than $c$.
2. When $v$ is equal to $c$: Formula isn't valid because $0/0$ is not defined.

**Note:** While the answer is fine for *general* massless particle, it's not good for photons (ask relativistic physicists). Relativistic equations have $c$ due to the fact that it is a postulate of Einstein that photons already have this speed. So, it's not good for us to get to there in reverse.
So, answer for relativistic guys: Its framework for Relativistic Physics. We never needed to accelerate photons to $c$. It was already running at this speed.

Comment: this was a fine answer, except for the note.  Modern physicists start with Minkowski space as their basic postulate when deriving special relativity.  They don't rely upon Einstein's two postulates as their primary motivation.

Comment: "it was already running at this speed" huh? So what about the conversion of mass into electromagnetic energy?

Comment: @Larry What do you want to say? Please, elaborate. And, why are you more specific to electromagnetic energy?

Comment: when mass is converted into electromagnetic energy by the annihilation of an electron and positron, a photon is produced. How do you know that the photon instantaneously acquires the velocity c upon creation?

Comment: @Larry Photons are produced with that speed. What's the problem? There's no inertial reference frame in which photons are at rest. Its the framework of whole relativistic physics.

Answer (score 10):

> If it requires infinite amount of energy to travel at the speed of
>   light then how photon attains this speed

That's not quite right.  You're thinking of the energy required to *accelerate* a *massive* object to $c$ which is impossible thus the infinity.

However, there is no reference frame in which photons are at rest.  An object with speed $c$ in one frame has speed $c$ in all frames (thus the *invariant* speed).

Comment: This is sort of a non-answer.  You might as well say it is an observed axiom that photons always travel at c and leave it at that.

Answer (score 2):

According to special relativity

$$
\frac vc = \frac {pc}E = \frac {pc}{\sqrt{(mc^2)^2+(pc)^2}}
$$

For $m=0$ we have $pc=E$ and thus $v=c$, whereas for $m\not=0$ we have $pc<E$ and thus $v<c$.

Comment: @cristoph:can you please put it in few words as well..say for layman !!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good article on the mass of the photon, which answers your question.
http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/ParticleAndNuclear/photon_mass.html

The concept of relativistic mass is just a construct.  A particle only has one mass; its rest mass and it is constant.  It does not increase with particle velocity.  This article, The Concept of Mass, should help explain.  https://www.worldscientific.com/phy_etextbook/6833/6833_02.pdf

The Wikipedia article on "Mass in special relativity" is very good also.

Here is a quote from an expert on the subject.

> It is not good to introduce the concept of the mass $M = m\sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}$ of a moving body
>   for which no clear definition can be given. It is better to introduce
>   no other mass concept than the ’rest mass’ m. Instead of introducing M
>   it is better to mention the expression for the momentum and energy of
>   a body in motion.

— Albert Einstein in letter to Lincoln Barnett, 19 June 1948

Comment: What's in the physics isn't a construct? You are dumping relativistic physics by one hand. Remember, mass is a form of Energy (E=mc^2). So, it'll increase.

Comment: You should read the article you put in the answer. It doesn't say, the mass wouldn't be increased. It says that rest mass of photon is zero, so relativistic mass would be zero, too (see formula in my answer).

Comment: There are two problems here.  1) Photons don't have mass; rest, relativistic or otherwise.  2) The mass of all particles is invariant.  It doesn't increase with speed.  The correct equation is E^2 = (mc^2)^2 + (pc)^2 or E = \gamma mc^2, where \gamma is the Lorentz factor.  If you learned that the mass of a particle increases with speed, you were misinformed.  All the particle physics experiments have shown otherwise.  Ask me how I know (hint: I work at the LHC).

Comment: 1) Its not a problem at all. Tell me how its a problem. 2) For rest mass, $p=0$. Put that in your equation, you'll get $E=mc^2$. So, this equation clearly tells rest mass is an energy. How can you not increase an Energy? Soooo, this is level of a LHC scientist?

Comment: 1) Its not a problem at all. Tell me how its a problem. 2) For rest mass, $p=0$. Put that in your equation, you'll get $E=mc^2$. So, this equation clearly tells rest mass is an energy. How can you not increase an Energy? Soooo, this is level of a LHC scientist?

Comment: The rest mass was always a constant. Its not new..

Comment: Also, you must know that the complete Energy equation you've posted has to do with relativistic mass too, not just rest mass... You don't know even a basic conceptual things of physics and are boasting that you work at LHC.

Comment: In both the equations I posted, I did not use relativistic mass.  I used rest mass.

Comment: The problem I have with your answer is simple. Relativistic mass is not a physical quantity. In reality, the mass of a particle doesn't not increase with Energy. E^2 = (mc^2)^2 + (pc)^2 applies to both massive and massless objects and is boost invariant. I suggest using it in the future. E=mc^2 creates confusion and misconceptions and does not apply to massless particles. I wish I could have just commented on your answer, but for some reason I don't have that ability. Since I could only create a new answer and you are not supposed to reference another answer in your answer, that's what I did

Comment: For your kind info, we use the relativistic mass to distinguish it with classical mass. In fact, there's only one type of mass from the perspective of relativistic physics. And, you're saying its not physical quantity?

Comment: Plus, you must know: $p=mv$ where $m$ is variable mass. So, you used relativistic mass in your equations.

Comment: One more thing: When you multiply *Lorenz Factor* with rest mass, it becomes relativistic mass (see formula in my answer). So, you've included relativistic mass with $E=mc^2$, unknowingly. :D For sure, your physics is dull.

Comment: When we measure or quote the mass of a particle, we are only talking about the invariant mass.  No one who actually does this for a living would ever think about a particle in terms of relativistic mass.  I wrote two equations I thought would improve the clarity of your answer: $E^2=(mc^2)^2 + (pc)^2$, which would have avoided the divide-by-zero problem, and $E=\gamma mc^2$.  Now that you mention it, if I were to write the momentum in terms of velocity, I would write $p=\gamma mv$.  I did not state $p=mv$, nor did I write $E=mc^2$.

Comment: When you add *Lorentz Factor* in momentum, a physical quantity having dimension of mass changes. What would you say it?

Comment: Your equations clearly contain *Lorentz Factor*.. It means divide-by-zero problem can't be avoided.

Comment: $E^2=(mc^2)^2+(pc)^2$.  Since photons are massless, the equation reduces to $E=pc$. In this case, $p\neq\gamma mv$.  The momentum of a photon is $p=h/\lambda$ and $\lambda>0$.  Therefore, there is no divide-by-zero issue.  Also, since $\lambda>0$, the energy of a photon is always finite.  I should have just written that as my answer rather than trying to correct your misconception.  Oh well.

Comment: Hold on... Why are you entering wave model while talking purely about particles (with rest mass ju-ju)?

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell if that was a serious question or if you are trolling.  I've been giving you the benefit of the doubt so far.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a divide in that equation?  Also, even if he said that, it that still considered true?  (He also said he didn't believe in quantum mechanics.)

Answer (score 1):

> If it requires infinite amount of energy to travel at the speed of light then how photon attains this speed? Its source is never infinitely sourced.

Photons, like gluons, are massless particles. When we speak of 'massless', we mean the rest mass or invariant mass of an object. That is, this quantity is constant to all observers. Photons can travel in the speed of light c because of this property (being massless). If not, then it will require an infinite amount of energy to make a photon with mass travel at the speed of light.